# Processing Non-Well-Formed HTML with DOM

Tags: dom, data-mining

I have got a HTML which has obtained from a web site's source code. Im sending data with post method from my page to the web site, and the response is source code. I need some text in the source.

The document is non-well-formed. So, i can not use DOM, and i can not separate tag and data with DOM.
How can i separate tag and data, and how can i get the only data?

I'm using PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which Html Parser is best?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-best)

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238036/java-html-parsing

Comment: Later I added, I'm using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something about getting data from html source code. I said in question, im using PHP.
I will use preg_match_all function and regular expression. Hopefully, i can overcome ;)

Thx to all who interested ;)