# how to extract content from <div> tag java

Tags: java, html, extract

i have a serious problem.
i would like to extract the content from  tag such as:

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="sub-content">Sub content here</div>
      Main content here </div>
```

output i would expect is:

> Sub content here
> Main content here

i've tried using regex, but the result isn't so impressive.
By using:

```
Pattern.compile("<div>(\\S+)</div>");
```

would return all the strings before the first <*/div> tag
so, could anyone help me pls?

Comment: Don not use Regular expression for HTML parsing. Use a HTML parser, refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238036/java-html-parsing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend avoiding regex for parsing HTML. You can easily do what you ask by using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String html = "<html><head/><body><div class=\"main-content\">" +
            "<div class=\"sub-content\">Sub content here</div>" +
            "Main content here </div></body></html>";
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements divs = document.select("div");
    for (Element div : divs) {
        System.out.println(div.ownText());
    }
}
```

---

In response to comment: if you want to put the content of the `div` elements into an array of `String`s you can simply do:

```
    String[] divsTexts = new String[divs.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < divs.size(); i++) {
        divsTexts[i] = divs.get(i).ownText();
    }
```

---

In response to comment: if you have nested elements and you want to get own text for each element than you can use jquery multiple selector syntax. Here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String html = "<html><head/><body><div class=\"main-content\">" +
            "<div class=\"sub-content\">" +
            "<p>a paragraph <b>with some bold text</b></p>" +
            "Sub content here</div>" +
            "Main content here </div></body></html>";
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements divs = document.select("div, p, b");
    for (Element div : divs) {
        System.out.println(div.ownText());
    }
}
```

The code above will parse the following HTML:

```
<html>
<head />
<body>
<div class="main-content">
<div class="sub-content">
<p>a paragraph <b>with some bold text</b></p>
Sub content here</div>
Main content here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and print the following output:

```
Main content here
Sub content here
a paragraph
with some bold text
```

Comment: err...what if i would like to add each <div> content into array? any suggestion? thanks

Comment: @kyo21: I added some code to my answer to answer your question on having the `div` contents into an array.

Comment: oh, sorry, i need ur explanation again, i use method element.text() to acquire all text inside <div>tag, i've added tag <p>at div content, but the result: -Sub content here Main content here
                         - Sub content here
how could this happen?

Comment: @kyo21: `text()` gets the combined text of this element and all its children. See [jsoup javadocs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/index.html?org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html)

Comment: @kyo21: I'm not quite sure what html you have now, but note that if you have two nested `div` tags each containing text, and you use the `text()` method, then the text of the innermost `div` tag is printed twice: once when you call `text()` on the outer `div`, and once when you call it on the inner `div` (the `for` loop process all `div` tags). I hope this helps.

Comment: i'm workin on extracting content from news web page, most of them have nested div tags containing text tag: <p>,<b>,etc. using text()method would obviously get all text contents, but printed the innermost <div> contents twice as u said. how to prevent this? do u have any idea or any other methods? the reult i would expect:
- Main content here 
- Sub content here , Thanks

Comment: @kyo21: well, why don't you use `ownText()` as in my example? That returns only the text of the element, and not that of its nested elements. So, you can select the elements that you're interested in, process them one by one, and call `ownText()` to retrieve their own text (if any).

Comment: yeah, it's true but ownText() will not return content inside <p>,<b> tag,,
err...or i just remove the <p>,and <b> tag, so it will not bother me anymore??
anyway, thanks for your help ... :)

Comment: @kyo21: oh that's easy: Jsoup supports CSS/jquery selector syntax, so you can write `document.select("div, p, b")` :) I've edited my answer to address your comment. I hope this helps.

Comment: @MarcoS out of curiosity, 
does jsoup has any method to remove a particular tag, ex:
i would like to remove tag <div clas="...."> inside my html? i guess it will help me alot in future

Comment: @kyo21: as far as I know, yes: have a look at [remove](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#remove%28%29) in jsoup javadaoc

Comment: ah, there is... 
it's said this method will remove all the available child nodes also right?
if i want to remove only the <div> tag in: '<div>text</div>', it's impossible for me to retain the "text" .. isn't it?

Comment: @kyo21: I don't remember: try ... and if not, browse the javadoc to look at what other methods do :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="main-content" id="mainCon">
    <div class="sub-content" id="subCon">Sub content here</div>
 Main content here </div>
```

From this code if you want to get the result you have mentioned

Use `document.getElementById("mainCon").innerHTML` it will give **Main content here** along with sub div but you parse that thing.

And similarly for sub-div you can use the above code sniplet i.e. `document.getElementById("subCon").innerHTML`

Comment: @kyo21 : Yes you give manual id to each div and you can also give it dynamically with javascript.