# How to get the text from div which contains other WebElement along with actual text?

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, automation

I am stuck in to automate one of the functionality in my current project using  Selenium TestNG. 
There is scenario where I want to get the text **(The answer you entered was not correct.)** from the div given in the source code. I am using `element.getText()` method to get the content but I am not able to get the text it carries.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advanced.

```
<div class="error">
<h2 class="visually-hidden">Error message</h2>
<div class="icon">
<svg version="1.1" height="24" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
</div>
The answer you entered was not correct.
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your xpath or the locator used?

Comment: use
`$('.error').text()`
may be it help..

Comment: @Murthi Thank you  for quick response, I am using CSS Selector (.error)

Comment: @NimishaMolia I am using java, This would be great if you could give the same approach in java. Thank you for response. `element.getText()` is not working

Comment: Please go to this post [extract content from div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026615/how-to-extract-content-from-div-tag-java). May be this will solve your problem.

Comment: Perfect :) This is what I was looking for.  A big Thank you @VaisakhPS

Answer (score 1):

You can get test using this...

```
   String text=  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='error']/h2/div")).getText();
 //print text
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be fine with:

```
// Assuming driver is instance of your WebDriver object
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.error")).getText();
```