# Get index of html element

Tags: java

i have html code that looks like the following:

```
String html = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\"></style></head><body><div style=\"font-family:times new roman,new york,times,serif;font-size:14pt\">first text<br><div><br></div><div style=\"font-family: times new roman,new york,times,serif; font-size: 14pt;\"><br><div style=\"font-family: times new roman,new york,times,serif; font-size: 12pt;\"><font size=\"2\" face=\"Tahoma\"><hr size=\"1\"><b><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">one:</span></b> second text<br><b><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">two:</span></b> third text<br><b><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">three:</span></b> fourth text<br><b><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">five:</span></b> fifth text<br></font><br>";
```

and i was wondering how to get the index of the third div ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DOM/XML parser might be better, depending on what you need to do. But the simple way would be:

```
int index = -1;
for(int i=0; i < 3; i++){
   index = html.indexOf("<div",index + 1);
   if(index == -1)
      throw new Exception();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use a DOM parser to do this. If you have proper XML (valid XHTML) content, you can use an XML parser as well.

And to which library to choose, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java) helps you.

*Update*: as far as I can see, your content is not valid XML. So [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238036/java-html-parsing) may be better for you.

Comment: is there's any samples for something like i want to do ?

Comment: for which? the valid or the not valid part?

Comment: what is the not valid part you are talking about ?

Comment: the valid XML (valid XHTML) or the one you posted in your OP