# Source from HTML

Tags: android

I want to get the source code from various url so that i can parse them, is there any way to do this?

I tried some solutions but they where to slow, i need to get the source from 20 website the fastest way possible.

Thank you for the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) in android successfully. Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238036/java-html-parsing) SO question