# Java regexp complicated pattern

Tags: java, html, regex

I have a string like this (made from HTML source code):

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <tr>First</tr>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Second</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <tr>
      <td>Upper</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lower</td>
    </tr>
  </td>
</tr>
```

but in one line - I divided it to make it look better.
What I want to achieve is a regular expression that will capture whole rows of this table, so the matches are:

```
<td>
  <tr>First</tr>
</td>
```

,

```
<td>Second</td>
```

,

```
<td>
  <tr>
    <td>Upper</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lower</td>
  </tr>
</td>
```

The most simple options:

- `<tr>.*</tr>` - catches everything
- `<tr>.*?</tr>` - catches from the first `<tr>` to the first `</tr>`.

I want it to catch corresponding tags. Can anybody help?

Comment: Use an HTML parser to parse HTML.  And in future, please review the ***preview*** carefully before posting.

Comment: Use something like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org) or you'll get [burned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238036/java-html-parsing

Comment: use a counter...++ the <td> tags and -- the </td> tags, anytime the counter hits zero print

Comment: You should **not** use a regex for parsing HTML. This answer provides a fantastic explanation why you shouldn't do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @ExpertSystem  :)  That is a classic.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I know :) It's the best answer ever !!!

Comment: @AndrewThompson I think SO should put this link in the face of the user if it sees `regex` and `html` as a tag combination ;)

Comment: This is possible using regex using recursive pattern `(?R)` which Java doesn't support. Here's a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/tM3fO4) using PHP PCRE flavor, note that it doesn't work like expected but it's just a [poc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept). So you're better off using an html parser.

Comment: `<tr>First</tr>` is invalid html by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use html parsing engine [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) and run something like this to pull out rows from your table

```
String url = "a.html";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

Elements rows = doc.select("table tr");
```