# Are there alternatives to javax.swing.text.* for android?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java / Android, so please be patient. Thank you in advance for your time. I'm writing a simple android app that will scan a web page's source for a=href links and return them

I have googled for about 2 days now and can't find any definitive answer, hence my question to SO.
Currently I'm using the following imports which are generated by eclipse when using Ctrl-Shift-O

```
import javax.swing.text.EditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
```

The problem is that when I run my android app, it crashes on the code that uses these libs (code below).

I need to find a way to do this without using the javax.swing imports. I have managed to figure out that android.text.html has some functionality, but not what I need.

Are there any Android imports that I can use to do the following, or is there a way to make the javax.swing.text.* imports work with android?

Code here  :

```
 try {  

    URLConnection conn = params[0].openConnection();

    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Code fails here for the new declarations");
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    EditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
    HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) kit.createDefaultDocument();

    kit.read(rd, doc, 0);

    HTMLDocument.Iterator it = doc.getIterator(HTML.Tag.A);


while (it.isValid()) {
            SimpleAttributeSet s = (SimpleAttributeSet) it.getAttributes();
            String link = (String) s.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF);

            if (link != null) {

              if (link.contains("naruto") && !link.contains("http://mangastream.com")){
                  // find the chapter number / id and print to console

                  String chapterNumber = link.replace("http://readms.com/r/naruto/", "");
                  // System.out.println("Chapter = " + chapterNumber.substring(0,3));
                  // System.out.println("ChapterID = " + chapterNumber.substring(4,8));
                  if (!registeredChapters.containsKey(chapterNumber.substring(0,3))){
                      registeredChapters.put(chapterNumber.substring(0,3),chapterNumber.substring(4,8));                     

                  }
              }      

            }
      it.next();
    }


    //appendToFile("Done with URL processing");
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Current chapters / id's found: ");

    }

catch (IOException ioe){
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}

catch (Exception e){
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
}

catch (Throwable t){
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG,t.getClass().getName());
}
```

Comment: I don't understand--you're just trying to display links? Do you want them clickable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I'm writing a simple android app that will scan a web page's source for a=href links and return them

Use an HTML parser to parse HTML.

> Currently I'm using the following imports

None of which are general-purpose HTML parser. Use an HTML parser to parse HTML.

A search on `java html parser` on a major search engine turns up:

- [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)
- [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)
- and [a Web page enumerating many other HTML parsers for Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers)

The search also turns up [Java HTML Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238036/java-html-parsing) and [Which HTML Parser is the best?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-best) from here on StackOverflow, and many other resources as well.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare. Thank you for the answer. I am not sure what you mean by 'None of which are general-purpose HTML parser' (are they or are they not general purpose?), but I will try jsoup. It looks like it might do what I'm looking for

Comment: @3wiel: `HTMLEditorKit` is an editor. It, and its support classes that you imported, is for editing HTML. It is not designed to support parsing HTML for any other purpose in Java (let alone in Android where the class simply does not exist). Use an HTML parser to parse HTML.

Comment: stupid comments..can't be edited...Hi CommonsWare. Thank you for the answer. I am not sure what you mean by 'None of which are _general-purpose_ HTML parser' (are they or are they not general purpose? -> javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit seems general purpose to me), but I will try jsoup as per your suggestion. It looks like it might do what I'm looking for