# Removing javascript from html file

Tags: java, html, xml, parsing

I'm supposed to parse an html page and display some search results from that page, i have seen some codes that do parsing, but they all do parsing on XML files. I have tried to convert the html file into XML file to parse it, but it didn't work. My guess was that because it contains some java script. I have Googled how to remove java scripts from HTML files but the result were somehow related to security and i didn't understand what i should do. Also i have searched in similar questions here , they mentioned something called Jtidy and DeXSS, but also i didn't get how these are supposed to help me remove the script from the html page so that i can convert it to XML

The code i'm using to convert html to XML is this

```
InputStream isInHtml =null;
URL url  = null;
URLConnection connection =null;
DataInputStream disInHtml =null;
FileOutputStream fosOutHtml =null;
FileWriter fwOutXml =null;
FileReader frInHtml=null;
BufferedWriter bwOutXml =null;
BufferedReader brInHtml=null;

try {
    frInHtml = new FileReader("./Lib.html");
    brInHtml = new BufferedReader(frInHtml);
    SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
    Document jdomDocument = saxBuilder.build(brInHtml);
    XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter();

    try {
        outputter.output(jdomDocument, System.out);
        fwOutXml = new FileWriter("./Lib.xml");
        bwOutXml = new BufferedWriter(fwOutXml);
        outputter.output(jdomDocument, bwOutXml);
        System.out.flush();
    }
    catch (IOException e)  {}        
}
catch (IOException e) {}  
finally {
    System.out.flush();
    try{
        isInHtml.close();
        disInHtml.close();                      
        fosOutHtml.flush();
        fosOutHtml.getFD().sync();
        fosOutHtml.close();
        fwOutXml.flush();
        fwOutXml.close();
        bwOutXml.close();
    }
    catch(Exception w) {}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, Java and Javascript are two *very* different things.

Comment: what I want is to remove java script from html page using java , so I shouldn't tagged javascript?

Comment: Tagging as javascript is usually only done if you're trying to write javascript yourself.

Comment: Oh Ok I will be more careful next time thanks

Comment: Also, please write "javascript", not "java script". The latter implies a script written in Java.

Comment: HTML is not XML, and you won't be able to parse HTML with an XML parser. Removing the JavaScript from the file won't make HTML XML. Look at JSoup, which is an HTML parser.

Comment: I want to remove javascript so that I can convert html to xml and use xml parser

Comment: honestly, @JBNizet is right.  Use JSoup to do this.  A lot of "html" on the web isn't actually valid XML.

Comment: I downloaded Jsoup but I don't know how to use it I can't find any useful examples on how to use it

Comment: This can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238036/java-html-parsing