# matching and replacing hyperlinks with java

Tags: java, regex, html-parsing, web-scraping

I'm using a buffered reader to go through a HTML file & have to replace the full URL of any img file with a new path.

For example, one file I'm working on has 3 new paths to be found & I've declared them as final variables:

```
public static final String x_TAG="https://newsite.com/media/x.jpg";
public static final String y_TAG="https://newsite.com/media/y.jpg";
public static final String z_TAG="https://newsite.com/media/z.jpg";
```

Now I can read through the file & pattern match where these are in the file by:

```
Pattern imgPattern = Pattern.compile("(<\\s*img\\s*alt\\s*=\\s*\").*?(\"\\s*>)");
Matcher imgMatcher = imgPattern.matcher(replaceAllTags);

while(imgMatcher.find()) {
    System.err.println("match at "+imgMatcher.group());
}
```

That prints back:

```
match at <img alt="/oldSite.com/Images?action=AttachFile&amp;do=get&amp;target=Images/x.jpg" src="cc_files/Images_003.jpg" title="/oldSite.com/Images?action=AttachFile&amp;do=get&amp;target=Images/x.jpg" width="600">


match at <img alt="/oldSite.com/Images?action=AttachFile&amp;do=get&amp;target=Images/y.jpg" src="cc_files/Images_004.jpg" title="/oldSite.com/Images?action=AttachFile&amp;do=get&amp;target=Images/y.jpg" width="600">


match at <img alt="/oldSite.com/Images?action=AttachFile&amp;do=get&amp;target=Images/z.jpg" src="cc_files/Images.jpg" title="/oldSite.com/Images?action=AttachFile&amp;do=get&amp;target=Images/z.jpg" width="600">**
```

So what's the best way to find & append the new URL for each image?

Comment: What should your final result look like after appended?

Comment: <img alt=
  "https://newSite.com/media/x.jpg" src=
  "https://newSite.com/media/x.jpg" title=
  "https://newSite.com/media/x.jpg" width=
  "600" />

Comment: [The pony, he comes..](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418556)

Answer (score 0):

yet another person trying to match screen-scrape with regex. :-) i'm not saying it's nto possible, but another approach is using html parser like jsoup https://stackoverflow.com/a/6042593/81520 or other such library to parse the HTML you read in. Then for each IMG tag, edit the SRC attribute.