# Test if position/character is inside a HTML tag

Tags: java, html, parsing

What is the easiest way to find out if a position is in a HTML tag in a string containing html formatted text?

Example:

This could be my text:

```
This is a text <a href="http://foo.com"> and this </a> is also <b>part</b> of the <b /> text.
```

Given the position x, how can I test if I am currently in a HTML tag or not? I suppose I'll have to test if I am in one of these situations (* is my position):

```
- < * > ... </>
- <...> * </> 
- < * />
```

But what is an efficient approach to handle this?

Comment: It should be noted that your 3 situations are not mutually exclusive. That is: `<...> < * > ... </> </>` would satisfy 1 and 2.

Comment: True, but I'm working with pretty basic HTML in this case. Nested tags will not be present.

Comment: Okay, but as far as I know, the smallest possible valid HTML file has nested tags :). But this is just a string which may have just a piece of html I guess?

Comment: Indeed, it's not valid HTML by definition since there'll be no `<head>, <title>, <body>` sections, only links, image tags etc...

Answer (score 2):

You have some answers about it in this link:

[Java HTML Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238036/java-html-parsing)

Basically, use some library to do the html parsing. I personally used JSoup some months ago and it worked perfectly.

Next time search first ;)

Comment: If building a DOM representation of a (large) HTML document is not needed, a [SAX parser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/package-summary.html) would do pretty well. A `ContentHandler` is notified about every element; you can check for presence of the target string there.