# Extracting content from html tags using java

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I extracted data from an html page and then parsed the tags containing  tags like this now I tried different ways like extracting substring etc do extract only the title and href tags. but it'snot working..Can anyone help me. This is the small snippet of my output

my code

```
     doc  = Jsoup.connect("myurl").get();

    Elements link = doc.select("a[href]");
    String stringLink = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < link.size(); i++) 
    {

        stringLink = link.toString();
        System.out.println(stringLink);
     }
```

output

```
<a class="link" title="Waf Ad" href="https://www.facebook.com/waf.ad.54" 
data- jsid="anchor" target="_blank"><img class="_s0 _rw img" src="https:
//fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash1/t5/186729_100007938933785_
508764241_q.jpg" alt="Waf Ad" data-jsid="img" /></a>
<a class="link" title="Ana Ga" href="https://www.facebook.com/ata.ga.31392410" 
data-jsid="anchor" target="_blank"><img class="_s0 _rw img" src="https://
fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash1/t5/186901_100002334679352_
162381693_q.jpg" alt="Ana Ga" data-jsid="img" /></a>
```

Comment: Snippet of your code extracting the selective contents using jsoup would also help (it's tagged under jsoup)

Comment: @PopoFibo i tried it..but it's not working how can I get only the title content and href content

Comment: Even so, showing your efforts (ie, your code) is appreciated, even if said efforts turn fruitless

Comment: chopu, you have been asked for a code, not just for result. We can help by fixing your code but not by writing it for you from scratch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java HTML Parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238036/java-html-parsing)

Comment: Do you use a html parser as listed there: [http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers)

Comment: @Vladimir i had added my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `attr()` method of Element class to extract the value of attributes.

For example:

```
String href = link.attr("href");
String title = link.attr("title");
```

See this page for more: [Extract attributes, text, and HTML from elements](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)

Answer (score 3):

To get the page title, you can use

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("myurl").get();
String title = doc.title();
```

For getting the individual links from the different hrefs, you can use this

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
for(Element ele : links) {
    System.out.println(ele.attr("href").toString());
}
```

`attr()` method gives the content inside the matching attributed spedified to it in the given tag.

Comment: Sorry, did not see the title in the tags. For that, as @ashatte suggested, you can use  `attr("title")` to get it from individual tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution{
    public static void main(String[] args){

         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testCases = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

        while (testCases-- > 0) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();

            boolean matchFound = false;
            Pattern r = Pattern.compile("<(.+)>([^<]+)</\\1>");
            Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

            while (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(m.group(2));
                matchFound = true;
            }
            if ( ! matchFound) {
                System.out.println("None");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**REGULAR EXPRESSION EXPLAINATION:**

[image]