# Notify when web content change

Tags: java

Im new to java and working on a simple application that monitor an url and notify me when a table is updated whit new items. Looking at the entire page will not work as there are commercials that change all the time and they would give false positives.

My thought was to fetch the url line by line looking for the elements. For each element I will check to see if the element is already in an arraylist. If not the element is added to the arraylist and a notification is send.

What I need support with is not the exact code but advice if this would be a good approach and if I should store the elements in an array list or if I should use a file instead as there are 2 lines of text in each element.
Also It would be good to get recomandation on what methods and libs there would be good to look at.

Thanks in advance

Sebastian

Comment: The question as it formulated now accepts opinion-based answers, which is not preferred way to go at SO. Try to restate it somehow like "what is the best way to detect changes on webpage? [definition of changes] [restrictions about webpage] - whether ETag is available for example, can we rely on 302 Not Modified, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To check the site it'd probably be more stable to parse the HTML and work with an object representation of the DOM. I've never had to do this but in a [question regarding how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238036/java-html-parsing) another user suggested using [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/), maybe you could have a look at that.

As for storing the information (what you currently do in your ArrayList): this really depends on what you use your application for. If you only want to be notified of changes that occur during the runtime of your program this is perfectly fine. If you want to have the information persist you should find a way to store the information in the file system or database.