# Regex search with pattern containing (?:.|\s)*? takes increasingly long time

Tags: java, regex

My regex is taking increasingly long to match (about 30 seconds the 5th time) but needs to be applied for around 500 rounds of matches. 
I suspect catastrophic backtracking.
Please help! How can I optimize this regex:

```
String regex = "<tr bgcolor=\"ffffff\">\\s*?<td width=\"20%\"><b>((?:.|\\s)+?): *?</b></td>\\s*?<td width=\"80%\">((?:.|\\s)*?)(?=(?:</td>\\s*?</tr>\\s*?<tr bgcolor=\"ffffff\">)|(?:</td>\\s*?</tr>\\s*?</table>\\s*?<b>Tags</b>))";
```

EDIT: since it was not clear(my bad): i am trying to take a html formatted document and reformat by extracting the two search groups and adding formating afterwards.

Comment: The usual answer is : don't use regexp on HTML or XML....

Comment: [Obligatory reference.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5044950)

Comment: @Bruce how would you then solve this kind of problem?

Comment: You have `(?:.|\\s)+?` which is VERY inefficient. Changing it to `.+?` and using `Pattern.DOTALL` (or `(?s)` in the beginning of the pattern) is much better (or if you do not want to use dotall flag, just use `[\\s\\S]+?`). But using jsoup or another HTML-parser-based solution is the best.

Comment: @stribizhev thank you i will check if it is fast enough or if i will change my solution. in fact there are 70K lines to be matched..

Comment: @stribizhev you sir have fixed my problem thank you very much can you create a answer so i can vote you up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alternation `(?:.|\\s)+?` is very inefficient, as it involves too much backtracking.

Basically, all variations of this pattern are extremely inefficient: `(?:.|\s)*?`, `(?:.|\n)*?`, `(?:.|\r\n)*?` and there greedy counterparts, too (`(?:.|\s)*`, `(?:.|\n)*`, `(?:.|\r\n)*`). `(.|\s)*?` is probably the worst of them all.

**Why?**

The two alternatives, `.` and `\s` may match the same text at the same location, the both match regular spaces at least. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/H1shYh/4) taking 3555 steps to complete and `.*?` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/H1shYh/3) (with `s` modifier) taking 1335 steps to complete.

Patterns like `(?:.|\n)*?` / `(?:.|\n)*` in Java often cause a [Stack Overflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883448/java-regex-to-match-start-end-tags-causes-stack-overflow/38883498#38883498), and the main problem here is related to the use of alternation (that already alone causes backtracking) that matches char by char, and then the group is modified with a quantifier of unknown length. Although some regex engines can cope with this and do not throw errors, this type of pattern still causes slowdowns and is not recommended to use (only in ElasticSearch Lucene regex engine the `(.|\n)` is the only way to match any char).

**Solution**

If you want to match any characters including whitespace with regex, do it with

```
[\\s\\S]*?
```

Or enable singleline mode with `(?s)` (or `Pattern.DOTALL` `Matcher` option) and just use `.` (e.g. `(?s)start(.*?)end`).

**NOTE**: To manipulate HTML, use a dedicated parser, like jsoup. Here is an SO post discussing [Java HTML parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238036/java-html-parsing).

Comment: In Java, always use inline flag to make dot match any character. It has less overhead than character class solution

Comment: @DeVeXD3VeX: Actually, it is correct in all cases: using built-in structures/types/classes you get the most optimal performance. So, `(?s)` with `.` to match any character incuding newline is preferable.

Comment: @stribizhev thanks again! you really sped up my regex from taking 5 minutes increasing exponentially to about 5 seconds for every match