# RegEx linebreaks run into an StackOverflowError

Tags: java, regex, stack-overflow

I´m using `\\r\\n|\n` in my Java RegEx to match linebreaks. I don´t care about mac-like newlines. Everytime I run my code, I´m getting an StackOverflowError like this:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Neg.match(Pattern.java:4986)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4466)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Slice.match(Pattern.java:3870)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4502)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4502)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4683)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Dollar.match(Pattern.java:3621)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4170)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4466)
```

and so on...

The Error won´t occure if I remove the `\\r\\n`, so there is only `\\n`. But the result is not like its needed to be...

! Notice, I´m handling large inputs up to 140k lines and about 50k matches with 5-6 groups per match. Smaller inputs work as expected. An earlier version, using the same RegEx and the same inputs, worked as well too.

Thanks in advance ;)

**EDIT:** 
I´m accessing the java matcher by using `matcher.find()` in a while-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternation usually causes the stack overflow issue (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883448/java-regex-to-match-start-end-tags-causes-stack-overflow/38883498#38883498)). You may use the following pattern *without alternation* with an optional pattern:

```
\\r?\\n
```

Here, `\\r?`  matches one or zero CR symbols, and `\\n` matches just 1 LF symbol.

Or, use a generic

```
\\R
```

It is [supported beginning with Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883448/java-regex-to-match-start-end-tags-causes-stack-overflow/38883498#38883498

Comment: Isn't the regex engine supposed to handle line breaks generically if you *ask* for a `\n`? I thought that was supposed to match *all* forms of line breaks.

Comment: @ClasG: I can see that [*`\n` (matches) The newline (line feed) character ('\u000A')`*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: \\r?\\n isin´t working in my case... still getting the StackOverflowError :/

Comment: Ok, what about `\R`? Also, what does *An earlier version* mean? Version of what?

Comment: IntelliJ Idea is telling me, that its an 'illegal/unsupported escape sequence'

Comment: Did you use double backslashes? `"\\R"`?

Comment: An earlier version of my code, containing the same function, handling the RegEx and dealing with the same inputs...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122094/discussion-between-schnicker-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: Ok, just to summerize our [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122094/discussion-between-schnicker-and-wiktor-stribizew): the `\r?\n` works for you and `\R` does not (since you are using Java7). There are 2 strings that still crash the code, but since the data is sensitive and you cannot share it, the current solution is good-enough.

Comment: indeed :) I guess, the problem is a double linebreak I need to check... I´ll try to solve this for my own :D Thanks for your help

Comment: If you do not care about empty lines, you might as well use `[\r\n]+`