# Matching large regular expression gives stack overflow error

Tags: java, regex, string, recursion, stack-overflow

I'm trying to match a long string with below regular expression

```
100(\\n|\\r\\n)13(\\n|\\r\\n)150(\\n|\\r\\n)17((\\n|\\r\\n)205(\\n|\\r\\n)206((\\n|\\r\\n)209){1,7}((\\n|\\r\\n)300){1,4}((\\n|\\r\\n)107){0,1}){1,9999}(\\n|\\r\\n)109(\\n|\\r\\n)
```

But every time I am getting

> stack over flow
>   error.

I've googled alot and seen most of the time that people say it happens due to recursion.

I couldn't understand what it means here. Could any one explain
**what recursion error is here**
and
**at what point it starts happening in regular expressions?**

Second, **what I can do with my regular expression to avoid this error?**

Comment: That regex in string literal context or in variable context?

Comment: Try replacing all `(\\n|\\r\\n)` with `\\r?\\n`

Comment: Which language/platform are you using? What is length of the string you trying to match?

Comment: @sln I'm using my regex in string literal. Likt String regex = "my regex exp";  But please share with me what makes a difference here and why and when it starts happening ? I want to know about reason behind that

Comment: Usually, this scenario `(()()()){1,9999}` is a backtracking nightmare.

Comment: @AnwarShaikh...I'm using my regex exp at java platform. And length of the string  could be dynamic and long. Like upto 5000 characters or may be more sometime

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew...Could you please tell me difference between using (\\n|\\r\\n) and \\r?\\n. Because in my case input file holding this long string could be in unix format or windows format. So that's why I did put OR condition to match both type of new line characters.

Comment: Look at all these pathways for backtracking `(()205()206(()209){1,7}(()300){1,4}(()107){0,1}){1,9999}`. If you get to 9998 before it craps out, it will try again and again. Put an atomic group around this block. `100(\\n|\\r\\n)13(\\n|\\r\\n)150(\\n|\\r\\n)17(?>(\\n|\\r\\n)205(\\n|\\r\\n)206(?>(\\n|\\r\\n)209){1,7}((\\n|\\r\\n)300){1,4}(?>(\\n|\\r\\n)107){0,1}){1,9999}(\\n|\\r\\n)109(\\n|\\r\\n)`

Comment: If you can't use atomic groups, one approach is to redesign - take off the {1,9999}, and match each one as a single. Do a global search. In your code you can check each match if they are continuous in their positions.

Comment: I think Java supports atomic groups. I'd use that for sure. And if you'd add the `Java` tag to your question it would help.

Comment: In Java, quantified alternations often lead to stack overflow issue. What to do: in Java 8, use `\\R`, or in your case, you may just avoiud using alternation at all using `\r?\n` - an optional CR followed with an LF.

Comment: There is no quantified alternations here...

Comment: @sln: See `((\\n|\\r\\n)300){1,4}`, then .... `{1,9999}`. These quantifiers quantify the groups with the alternations.

Comment: `(\\n|\\r\\n)` no quantification here. But the answer is (always has been) using atomic groups.. `(?>((\\n|\\r\\n)300){1,4})` at inner and outter levels. And there is some website to test this at.. forgot where though.

Comment: Anyway, the best solution is to use `[\r\n]+` if there is no need to count line breaks/consider empty lines. @kelly, here is my answer where I quote [the reason for the stack overflow issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883448/java-regex-to-match-start-end-tags-causes-stack-overflow/38883498#38883498).

Comment: But `\r?\n` is better, but underlying backtrack nightmare still there,  need atomic groups

Comment: @sln, or possessive quantifiers - `\r?+\n`

Comment: Ahh, could be, not sure Java has that... oh it does The real problem is this {1,9999}. And it represents a lot of nesting there doesn't it?

Comment: @Wiktor And did you know that `\R` is replaced with the string equivalent of `(?> all the stuff )` then reparsed as a state item ?? Ie. it's just shorthand notation that is useless, it's a macro.

Comment: @kelly Did any of the above comments help you?