# Regex large files in jvm

Tags: java, regex, kotlin, stack-overflow

I have a big html file, i want to parse it in kotlin or java, i'm trying
 first to to match everything between `<body` and `</body>`
using a simple regex like

```
<body(.|\n)+</body>
```

but surely i'm faced with the stackOverFlow error, 
here's the code in kotlin

```
//original html
val file= File("""/home/yazan/Documents/books.xml""")

//empty file
val file2= File("""/home/yazan/Documents/books2.xml""")

val reg="""<body(.|\n)+</body>""".toRegex()
val text= reg.find(file.readText())
text?.value?.let { file2.writeText(it) }
```

how can I regex large files in a memory-efficient way ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677038/how-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-in-java ... parsing html/xml with regular expressions ... isn't a good idea to begin with. And it doesn't get better when doing that with **large** input strings.

Comment: `"""<body([\s\S]*?)</body>"""`  or `"""(?s)<body(.*?)</body>"""`  can be used to match a string between two strings. Or unroll the pattern as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38883498/3832970).

Comment: yeah i'm planning to use a dom parser but i was experimenting in regex,, wouldn't regex be faster anyway ?